# How do I make a scope that is independent of any containing scope *and* does *not* start a new transaction?

Tags: c#, transactionscope

The following code opens a new transaction scope independent of any containing scope:

```cs
using (TransactionScope scope = new(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress, asyncFlowOption: TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    var connection = _connectionFactory.GetConnection()
    await connection.QueryAsync(...); // e.g. call DB with Dapper 
    await connection.QueryAsync(...); // e.g. another call 
}
```

(using Dapper)

****How do I make a scope that is independent of any containing scope *and* does *not* start a new transaction?****  Essentially, I want the "suppress" option as above, but in a "non-transaction scope".

Comment: Docs of Supress option say: The ambient transaction context is suppressed when creating the scope. All operations within the scope are done without an ambient transaction context. Isn't that already what you need?

Comment: Yes, but I also don't want a (non-ambient) transaction here.  In other words, I want my two queries to not be in any transaction at all.

Comment: Did you verify it indeed starts a transaction?

Comment: EVERYTHING runs in a transaction of some kind. If you have don't have another scope, an implicit transaction is created for you.

Comment: Right, but I don't open a transaction and I run two queries as in the example above, they won't run in the same transaction; the locks acquired in the first statement will be released before starting the second.

Comment: Evk, yes.  When you declare a TransactionScope, the containing code is in a transaction and locks acquired inside it will be held till the transaction is committed (after a call to `scope.Complete()`) or rolled back (the default).

Comment: What database you are using, sql server?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a thread without passing it a `DependentTransaction`. It will be independent. Create a function that runs the queries and use this:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// ...

var task = new Task(FunctionWithQueries);
task.RunSynchronously();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Transaction.Current` is null inside `TransactionScope` with `Suppress` option, so connection can't start new transaction because of scope - it has no way to find out scope even exists. If it starts new transaction it must be for another reason.

Note that above I assume you open fresh connection inside suppressed transaction scope, because you use:

```
var connection = _connectionFactory.GetConnection()
```

If you do NOT open fresh connection - then `Suppress` scope essentially does nothing in this case. Ambient transaction is null yes, but your connection already started a transaction before, and so your code inside suppress block will still run inside this same transaction (or it will just fail, for example Entity Framework will notice this situation and throw an exception).